# How to use Github search for pull request within a time range

Tags: github, github-search

I'm using https://github.com/pulls to run some queries to find PRs reviewed by team members following examples at https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/searching-on-github/searching-issues-and-pull-requests

This is what I'm using right now,

```
is:pr review:approved reviewed-by:user merged:>=2021-07-01 archived:false is:closed
```

Is there a way to specify time range? PRs reviewed between 2021-07-01 and 2021-08-01

It doesnt work if I try

```
is:pr review:approved reviewed-by:user merged:<2021-08-01 merged:>=2021-07-01 archived:false is:closed
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`merged:2021-07-01..2021-08-01`

`merged` qualifier shouldn't be used twice as that won't be a valid query.

This query should work for you:

```
is:pr review:approved reviewed-by:user merged:2021-07-01..2021-08-01 archived:false is:closed
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in pull request creation date,

```bash
is:pr created:2022-08-29..2022-09-02 author:@me
```

[image]

You can skip/change `author` to view pull requests by different user. `@me` represents the currently logged in user.